# Android Espresso IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout not working

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I have a few classes to test deep links. Each class test 1 deep link.

There are few tests that always terminate correctly at 10+ seconds when I run them individually but always take more than 45 seconds to finish when I run them together.

[image]
Note that all these tests are supposed to fail all the times now (I haven't done the implementation for them) so the results should not vary.

Am I using `IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout` wrong?

My test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class DeepLinkActivityBagTest extends MyActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public MyActivityTestRule<DeepLinkActivity> activityTestRule =
            new MyActivityTestRule<DeepLinkActivity>(DeepLinkActivity.class) {
                @Override
                protected Intent getActivityIntent() {
                    Intent intent = super.getActivityIntent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("xxx://bag"));
                    return intent;
                }
            };

    @Test
    public void testCorrectScreenOpened() {
        setUpWait();

        String expectedToolbarTitle = "shopping bag" + mToolbarTitleSuffix;
        onView(withTextIgnoreCase(expectedToolbarTitle)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

Its parent class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyActivityTest {
    @Rule
    public MyActivityTestRule<DeepLinkActivity> activityTestRule;
    protected String mToolbarTitleSuffix;

    @Before
    public void prepare() {
        if (!BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals(ENV_PRODUCTION)) {
            mToolbarTitleSuffix = String.format(" (%s)", BuildConfig.FLAVOR);
        }
    }

    @After
    public void resetCountry() {
        if (activityTestRule != null) {
            PrefUtils.clear(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
            PrefUtils.setCurrentCountryCode(activityTestRule.getmCurCountryCode());
            PrefUtils.setCurrentLangCode(activityTestRule.getmCurLangCode());
        }
    }

    protected void setUpWait() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Logger.e(e, "");
        }
        IdlingPolicies.setMasterPolicyTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

MyActivityTestRule:

```
public class MyActivityTestRule<D extends Activity> extends ActivityTestRule {
    private String mCurCountryCode;
    private String mCurLangCode;

    protected MyActivityTestRule(Class activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
    }

    public MyActivityTestRule(Class activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode) {
        super(activityClass, initialTouchMode);
    }

    public MyActivityTestRule(Class activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode, boolean launchActivity) {
        super(activityClass, initialTouchMode, launchActivity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeActivityLaunched() {
        super.beforeActivityLaunched();

        PrefUtils.setup(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
        mCurCountryCode = PrefUtils.getCurrentCountryCode();
        mCurLangCode = PrefUtils.getCurrentLangCode();
        PrefUtils.clear(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
        PrefUtils.setCurrentCountryCode("SG");
        PrefUtils.setCurrentLangCode("en");
    }

    String getmCurCountryCode() {
        return mCurCountryCode;
    }

    String getmCurLangCode() {
        return mCurLangCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know, that your tests are not isolated? `activityTestRule` from `DeepLinkActivityBagTest ` covers `activityTestRule` from `MyActivityTest`, which makes `@After` method always invoking nothing? Also 45 seconds is quite a [known amount of time in Espresso](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/issues/56), so please double check your logcat, which will definitely tell you more.

Comment: you use IdlingResource in wrong way, check this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/IdlingResourceSample

Comment: it's challenging to answer the question without the log from the failing test. As @R.Zagórski pointed out, you might be dealing with `MonitoringInstrumentation` default activity launch timeout that does not relate to espresso framework that much.

Comment: @ericn did you find a solution to that?